# Can you display terminal via hdmi

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, hdmi

I have a really broken up computer, the LCD screen is internally cracked and the WiFi doesn't work. I have a live Ubuntu CD that I wanted to try, to see if I like Ubuntu as much as Debian on other devices. I put the live CD in and it worked and booted the Ubuntu terminal.

The problem with this is that the computer would normally display the data over HDMI. Is there a way to display the terminal or start the GUI other than `startx` which I cannot see the output of. I do believe the dc has the GUI as when i checked the files it had some Ubuntu images for the background.[image]

Comment: You need to configure your laptop to not use the broken screen.  On my Dell laptops (all we get at work, love the NBDOS warranty) there is a function key to toggle between internal display only, external display only, or both displays.  If you have a similar key, set it up to external display only.  Then boot w/ the live disk and it should work.    Otherwise post more details about your HW - chipset and version for video, etc

Comment: Please clarify whether the cracked screen shows anything useful, and exactly what is displayed on HDMI.  (It sounds like the terminal is being displayed on one of them, but it's unclear which one.)

Comment: Just a guess but you might be able to preconfigure a usb linux drive to mirror content on all available displays.

Comment: Definitely possible. I've laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 and two monitors - one connected to HDMI, one to VGA,  and once it boots to login screen - the displays are mirrored, but after that I configured my laptop screen to be off and other to be extended.  It's an actual install,though, not a live USB. Going to TTY1 also works alright.

Comment: To change pre set settings i would just modify the etc and boot files right?  I will semd a picture of the lcd screen when i get home if needed but the windows setup automatically displayed in settings the ubuntu disk is booting straight to the terminal and startx/gnome-start are not opening the display. The disk does have a display and when i startx is says something aboit windows i can see little bloches on the left side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a virtual machine to run the disk.